# In Postgres 10 how to roll multiple matching rows into a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 10

I created simple example to try and demonstrate I have table1, and table 2, table 2 has fk into table1, so in example below rows 1,2,3 from table 2 link to 1 in table 1, and row 4 links to 2, and rows 5,6,7 from table 2 link to 3 in table 1

table1

```
pk     name
-----------------
1    | fred
2    | jane
3    | tom
```

table2

```
pk   fk   name
-----------------------
1  | 1  | blue
2  | 1  | yellow
3  | 1  | green
4  | 2  | red
5  | 3  | green
6  | 3  | yellow
7  | 3  | blue
```

What I would like to do is roll the value of table2 into one row get to the following result (or similar) so that I have one row with all the values

```
fred blueyellowgreen
jane red
tom  blueyellowgreen
```

the reason is I need to find where there are two sets of rows in table 2 with the same value, I can order by value to get the same order.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small issue with the sorting of the colors, but the built-in string_agg function takes care of the rest.

Try

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT fk, name FROM table2 ORDER BY fk, name)
SELECT table1.name, string_agg(CTE1.name, '') AS colors -- '' is delimiter
FROM table1 JOIN CTE1 ON table1.pk=CTE1.fk
GROUP BY table1.name
ORDER BY table1.name;
```

If you don’t like CTE style, you can easily rewrite this with a sub-SELECT.